# How much disk space do I need for running an Ubuntu Live CD?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, livecd

Do you know how much free disk space I need to run [an Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhhh, to run a LiveCD you don't need *any* space, the whole point is to run it from CD.

If you mean to *install* it on the other hand, check out the [Ubuntu Recommended System Specifications](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

- 1 GHz CPU (x86 processor (Pentium 4 or better))
- 1 GiB RAM (system memory)
- 15 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- 800 by 600 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

Internet access is helpful

Comment: ok so I dont need any free space to run ubuntu from live CD is this correct ?

Comment: Technically you don't even need a hard drive in the machine to be able to run a LiveCD, just a CD or DVD reader.  If you change anything and want the data to be persistent across reboots then you either need to install to hard drive or to a USB pen drive.